# vsto + differentiate attachments

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I need to get and save the attachments(s) from a mail item, but using the code below returns all attachments - meaning it also returns the embedded images like the sender's signature with logo which is an image. How can I differentiate a **true attachment vs. embedded images**? I have seen a lot from forums but it is still unclear to me.

```
public static void SaveData(MailItem currentMailItem)
{
    if (currentMailItem != null)
    {       
        if (currentMailItem.Attachments.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= currentMailItem.Attachments.Count; i++)
            {
                currentMailItem.Attachments[i].SaveAsFile(@"C:\TestFileSave\" + currentMailItem.Attachments[i].FileName);
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can check whether an attachment is inline or not by using the following [pseudo-code from MS Technet Forums](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/exchange2010/thread/542f0c0c-4de3-4752-9390-db33b8e45bca/).

```
if body format is plain text then
   no attachment is inline
else if body format is RTF then
   if PR_ATTACH_METHOD value is 6 (ATTACH_OLE) then
     attachment is inline
   else
     attachment is normal
else if body format is HTML then
   if PR_ATTACH_FLAGS value has the 4 bit set (ATT_MHTML_REF) then
     attachment is inline
   else
     attachment is normal
```

You can access the **message body format** using [`MailItem.BodyFormat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb207134%28v=office.12%29.aspx) and the **MIME attachment properties** using [`Attachment.PropertyAccessor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb175206%28v=office.12%29).

```cs
string PR_ATTACH_METHOD = 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x37050003';
var attachMethod = attachment.PropertyAccessor.Get(PR_ATTACH_METHOD);

string PR_ATTACH_FLAGS = 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x37140003';
var attachFlags = attachment.PropertyAccessor.Get(PR_ATTACH_FLAGS);
```